IntelliJ almost not running
I've been having this problem for several days now and I really don't know what to do because I'm kinda beginner at this. IntelliJ is building very very slow! Almost as if it is not running.
I have the Community Edition. I tried deleting caches, resetting the settings, and even downloading the Ultimate Edition with 30-day trial (but exactly the same problem for that too!!!).
I don't know what to do now.
I've tried:

invalidating the caches
increasing the heap size
resetting settings
installing IntelliJ Ultimate


Does your computer meet the system requirements?
You can also increase the amount of memory the JVM will allow the program to use, which may help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

yeah i did that but didn't work. today i turned off the ktolin plugin and the problem solved =\

Please create a YouTrack ticket regarding the issue.
It is also necessary to provide logs which should be captured for the performance scenario.
Thank you!

For anyone having the same problem:
I turned off the kotlin plugin and BOOM. problem solved :\
